# How do you forecast ARIMA with multiple regressors?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

The complete R data and code for my question is here: https://pastebin.com/QtG6A7ZX.

I am new to R and still a beginner when it comes to time series analysis, so please forgive my ignorance.

I am attempting to model and forecast some enrollment data with 2 dummy-coded regressors. I have already used `auto.arima` to fit the model:

`model <- auto.arima(enroll, xreg=x)`

Before I forecast with this model, I am attempting to test its accuracy by selecting only a part of the time series (1:102 instead of 1:112), and likewise, a partial list of regressors.

Based on `auto.arima`, I fit the partial model as follows:

`model_par <-arima((enroll_partial), c(1, 1, 1),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = 5), xreg=x_par)`

I have tried three different ways to forecast and get essentially the same error:

`fcast_par <- forecast(model_par, h=10) #error
fcast_par <- forecast(model_par, h=10, xreg=x_par) #error
fcast_par <- forecast(model_par, h=10, xreg=forecast(x_par,h=10)) #error`

> 'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns

I have tested using `auto.arima` with the partial data. That works, but gives me a different model and, although I specified 10 predictions, I get over 50:

`model_par2 <- auto.arima(enroll_partial, xreg=x_par)
fcast_par <- forecast(model_par2, h=12, xreg=x_par)
fcast_par`

So, my main question is, how do I specify an exact model and predict using more than 1 regressor given my data (see Paste Bin link above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forecast()` function is from the forecast package, and works with model functions that are from that package. This is why it is possible to produce forecasts from `auto.arima()` using `forecast(model_par2,xreg=x_fcst)`.

The `arima()` function comes from the stats package, and so there are no guarantees that it would work with `forecast()`. To specify your own ARIMA model, you can use the `Arima()` function, which behaves very similarly to `arima()`, but you will be able to produce forecasts from it using `forecast(model_par2,xreg=x_fcst)`.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I did the following: `model_partial <- Arima((enroll_partial), c(1, 1, 1),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = 5), xreg=x_par)` and `forecast(model_partial, h=10, xreg=x_par)`. Although I specified 10 predictions, I got over 50 point forecasts. Also, the model is not very accurate so I have to add more regressors or try to refit it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. One of them is that the various forecasting functions in R are making it (intentionally?) difficult on you.

The first problem is that you need to define the values of your regressors for the forecasting period. Extract the relevant data from `x` by using `window()`:

```
x_fcst <- window(x,start=c(2017,4))
```

The second problem is that `forecast()` (which dispatches to `forecast.Arima()`) is a red herring here. You need to use `predict()` (which dispatches to `predict.Arima()` - note the capitalization in both cases!):

```
predict(model_par,newxreg=x_fcst,h=nrow(x_fcst))
```

which yields

```
$pred
Time Series:
Start = c(2017, 3) 
End = c(2019, 1) 
Frequency = 5 
[1] 52.00451 52.00451 52.00451 52.00451 52.00451 52.00451 52.00451 52.00451
[9] 52.00451

$se
Time Series:
Start = c(2017, 3) 
End = c(2017, 3) 
Frequency = 5 
[1] 17.13345
```

You can also use `auto.arima()`. Confusingly enough, this time `forecast()` (which still dispatches to `forecast.Arima()`) *does* work:

```
model_par2 <- auto.arima(enroll_partial, xreg=x_par)
forecast(model_par2,xreg=x_fcst)
```

which yields

```
        Point Forecast     Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
2017.40       39.91035 17.612358  62.20834   5.808514  74.01219
2017.60       59.51003 32.783451  86.23661  18.635254 100.38481
2017.80       69.81000 39.290834 100.32917  23.134962 116.48505
2018.00       57.49140 23.601444  91.38136   5.661183 109.32162
2018.20       55.45759 18.503034  92.41214  -1.059524 111.97470
2018.40       34.57866 -7.306747  76.46406 -29.479541  98.63686
2018.60       52.30199  6.702068  97.90192 -17.437074 122.04106
2018.80       61.61591 12.582055 110.64977 -13.374900 136.60672
2019.00       50.47661 -1.765945 102.71917 -29.421485 130.37471
```

And yes, you do get five times as many predictions. The first column is an expectation forecast, and the others give prediction intervals. These are governed by the `level` parameter to `forecast()`.

Comment: And, to continue with the entire time series (not the partial one), do I have to forecast my regressor? I actually know the future values (given that it is dummy and the conditions won't change), so should I simply load new data with the appropriate amount of data needed?

Comment: You will need to specify the regressor values for the periods you wish to forecast. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "continue with the entire time series", do you mean an in-sample fit? Then you need the regressor values for the corresponding in-sample periods. For the future, you will either need to supply known values, or forecast the regressor itself. (Which is actually the same thing.)

Comment: Thank you. That does make sense. Going back to the original question, is there no way to use `forecast` with the custom model rather than `auto.arima`? The specified model is (1,1,1)(1,0,0)[5] for enroll (not enroll_partial). I'd like to use that model for the partial data. Your code above works for this situation using `predict` but `predict` does not seem as accurate compared to the `auto.arima` results, which are closer to the actual results. However, auto.arima with the enroll_partial gives a different model.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what precisely you are looking for. What custom model do you mean? What do you mean by "using" a model - refitting the coefficients with the model form staying the same, or just applying it without refitting to new data? Perhaps consider asking a new question with a clear minimal working example, and explaining precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I was referring to was taking the coefficients of the original ARIMA model for the original time series data (1997-2019) and applying them to the truncated data (1997-2017) in order to test the accuracy of the predictions of the model. I see now, from Mitchell O'Hara-Wild's comments, that I should use capital-A `Arima()` to specify a custom model.